# Generating pagination button numbers and dots

Tags: javascript, math, pagination

I am trying to generated pagination button labels based on a few rules, and can't quite wrap my head around this.

I have 2 inputs, `activePage`, which is the number of the current page and `pageCount` which is the total number of pages. Depending on these I should be generating the following outputs:

| `activePage` | `pageCount` | expected output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | `['&lt;','1','2','&gt;']` |
| 2 | 2 | `['&lt;','1','2','&gt;']` |
| 1 | 3 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','&gt;']` |
| 2 | 3 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','&gt;']` |
| 3 | 3 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','&gt;']` |
| 1 | 4 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','4','&gt;']` |
| 2 | 4 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','4','&gt;']` |
| 3 | 4 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','4','&gt;']` |
| 4 | 4 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','4','&gt;']` |
| 1 | 5 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','...','5','&gt;']` |
| 2 | 5 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','...','5','&gt;']` |
| 3 | 5 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','4','5','&gt;']` |
| 4 | 5 | `['&lt;','1','...','3','4','5','&gt;']` |
| 5 | 5 | `['&lt;','1','...','3','4','5','&gt;']` |
| 1 | 6 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','...','6','&gt;']` |
| 2 | 6 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','4', '...', '6','&gt;']` |
| 3 | 6 | `['&lt;','1','2','3','4', '...', '6','&gt;']` |
| 4 | 6 | `['&lt;','1','...','3','4', '5','6','&gt;']` |
| 5 | 6 | `['&lt;','1','...','4', '5','6','&gt;']` |
| 6 | 6 | `['&lt;','1','...','4', '5','6','&gt;']` |
| 4 | 7 | `['&lt;','1','...','3','4','5','...','7','&gt;']` |

The last pattern (4, 7) then repeats indefinitely, for example for 100 pages:
`activePage: 33, totalPages: 100`: `['&lt;', '1', '...' '32', '33', '34', '...', '100']`

I am stumped just trying to write down the mathematical rule behind this. Any help is appreciated.

What I ended up was this bunch of if statements, and then got stuck trying to write down the generalisation for when the page count is more than 6.

```
  const getPaginationButtons = (activePage: number, pageCount: number): string[] => {
    if(pageCount > 6) {
      // ... ?
    }

    if (pageCount === 6) {
      if(activePage === 1) {
        return ['1', '2', '3', '...', '6'];
      }

      // ... ?

      if(activePage === 6) {
        return ['1', '...', '4', '5', '6'];
      }
    }

    if (pageCount === 5) {
      const pages = [...new Array(pageCount)].map((_, index) =>
        (index + 1).toString()
      );

      if (activePage === 3) {
        return pages;
      }

      if (activePage < 3) {
        return pages.map((page) => (page === '4' ? '...' : page));
      }

      if (activePage > 3) {
        return pages.map((page) => (page === '2' ? '...' : page));
      }

      return pages;
    }

    if (pageCount <= 4) {
      const pages = [...new Array(pageCount)].map((_, index) =>
        (index + 1).toString()
      );
      return pages;
    }

    return [];
  };
```

Comment: where is code you have tried to obtain desired output?

Comment: @ZubairAhmd sry, edited the question to include the code, but not sure if it'll be any help. I got stuck trying to write a general rule, played around with some `reduce` and `map` statements, but so far nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the test cases passing with the following code, but I still believe there might be a better way to code this:

```
    const getPaginationButtons = (): string[] => {
    if (pageCount <= 4) {
      const pages = [...new Array(pageCount)].map((_, index) =>
        (index + 1).toString()
      );
      return pages;
    }

    const pages = ['1'];

    if (activePage >= 4) {
      pages.push('...');
    }

    if (activePage + 1 > pageCount) {
      pages.push((activePage - 2).toString());
    }

    if (activePage - 1 > 1) {
      pages.push((activePage - 1).toString());
    }

    if (activePage !== 1) {
      pages.push(activePage.toString());
    }

    if (activePage + 1 <= pageCount) {
      pages.push((activePage + 1).toString());
    }

    if (activePage - 1 <= 0) {
      pages.push((activePage + 2).toString());
    }

    if (activePage + 2 < pageCount) {
      pages.push('...');
    }

    if (activePage + 1 < pageCount) {
      pages.push(pageCount.toString());
    }

    return pages;
  };
```